# From an XY graph how can I get X that corresponds to Ymax?

Tags: python, max

I have different measurements (y) at specific time points (x). I would like to find the x that corresponds to the ymax for each set of measurements:

```
X=0,3,6,9,12 (up to 99)
Y1=1,1,2,5,2 (up to 33 numbers)
Y2=3,3,3,5,3 (up to 33 numbers)
```

So the answer I am looking for would be 9,9 for these two y.

I've covered the basics in Python and still not sure how to make a nice code

Thanks!

Comment: Why do `X` and `Y1`,`Y2` have different lengths?

Comment: They have the same length, maybe I wrote it in a confusing way. I have 33 numbers of x (as well as each y) but it's always x=x+3, so it goes up to 99, while the y experimental values are 33 random values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, you could do this using `argmax` from the `numpy` package, which returns the index of the max.

```
import numpy as np
X = [0, 3, 6, 9, 12]
Y1 = [1, 1, 2, 5, 2]
Y2 = [3, 3, 3, 5, 3]
X[np.argmax(Y1)]
# 9
X[np.argmax(Y2)]
# 9
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks!